# Associate git repo with existing fork network

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Using GitHub Enterprise, I forked a private repo. I then made the upstream repo public, which broke the 'fork' relationship between the public upstream and my private personal fork (as noted [here](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/#changing-a-private-repository-to-a-public-repository)). I've now also made my copy of the repo public. As far as I can tell, I can no longer make pull requests from my copy of the repo to upstream, because my copy is not recognized as a fork of upstream.

Can I re-associate my repo with the upstream repo as a fork?

Comment: This is probably something you should take up with GitHub Enterprise support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub support has removed fork relationships for me before, so I suspect they'd also be able to reattach you.

To do it on your own, I'd:

- Make a new fork of the upstream repo
- Change your personal fork's `origin` to the new fork

You'll lose GitHub history for your current fork (Pull Requests, etc.), but you'll be able to work with upstream again.

Comment: I wanted to avoid losing the history. GitHub Enterprise admins were able to reinstate the relationship.