# Github - create pull request between two disconnected repositories

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I have two repositories on Github containing the same project, but they are not one the fork of the other.

Is there a way to do a pull request from one repository to the other? Is there a way to declare that the two repositories as forks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only submit pull requests between repositories that have been forked from each other. GitHub support has removed a fork connection for me before, and [I've heard they'll create one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893077/associate-git-repo-with-existing-fork-network/30896366#comment49901597_30896366), so you should give them a shot. If you want to do it yourself, you'll need a new repository, but can do this:

- Fork a new repo from repo A
- Add it as a remote from repo B
- Push to it and submit a pull request to A

This will work as long as your two repos really are the same, and have a common ancestry. If they don't, you can ship code between them by [creating and applying a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory), but that won't connect them at all on GitHub.